# Evaluating a trigonometric integral

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, definite-integrals

Show that
$$
\int \frac{y^2\, dx - x^2\, dy}{x^2 + y^2} = -\frac{4a}{3}
$$
where Life is a semi circle at $x = a\cos t$ and $y = a\sin t$ from $t = 0$ to $t = \pi$. I tried it but this is where I stopped,
$$
a\int (\sin^3t - \cos^3t)\, dt.
$$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! It's customary (and appreciated) if you [format your answers](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex). The [site tour](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) may be useful, as well. :)

Comment: @user86418 thanks,and I'm waiting for the answer

Comment: Yes that is how the question is

Comment: Hint for the integral of $\sin^{3} t\, dt$: Write $\sin^{2} t = 1 - \cos^{2} t$, then use the substitution $u = \cos t$. The other term can be handled similarly.

Comment: Ok but for I'm waiting

Comment: I substitude but gave me a{intergral (1-cos^2t)sint-cos^2tU\frac{du}\-sint

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: You have
\begin{align*}
\int \sin^{3} t\, dt
  &= \int (1 - \cos^{2} t) \sin t\, dt && \sin^{2} t = 1 - \cos^{2} t, \\
  &= -\int (1 - u^{2})\, du && u = \cos t,\quad du = -\sin t\, dt. \\
\end{align*}
Can you take things from there?

The other term
$$
\int \cos^{3} t\, dt
$$
can be handled similarly.

Comment: I didn't not understand it sir

Comment: Sir,just conclude for me please

Comment: Do you have a teacher you can consult? If you're trying to evaluate line integrals (or just pass calculus) without being fluent in basic antiderivatives, you need more help than you can get at Math.SE.

Comment: I tried but again but I get -sint-\frac{sin^3pi}/3,and I used pi=90, I get \frac{-2a}/3